# check duplicates in unhashable list of lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples, hashable

I have the following list:

```
L = [['a', 'b'], ['x'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']]
```

I want to check whether there are duplicates in the list.

Have  tried:

```
def checkIfDuplicates_(listOfElems):
    ''' Check if given list contains any duplicates '''    
    for elem in listOfElems:
        if listOfElems.count(elem) > 1:
            return True
    return False
```

and

```
len(L)==len(set(L))
```

and turn each sublist into tuples

```
check_L = list(set(tuple(L) for x in L))
```

Not working

Answer (score 1):

You were actually really close with this:

```
check_L = list(set(tuple(L) for x in L))
```

There is a minor mistake, in that you are using `tuple(L)` where you actually want `tuple(x)`. If we correct that, we get:

```
>>> list(set(tuple(x) for x in L))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('x',), ('a', 'b')]
```

And to turn back into a nested list, we can do this:

```
>>> [list(y) for y in set(tuple(x) for x in L)]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Hope that helps!